# how to connect between 2 or more apps with high performance

Tags: python, node.js, api, socket.io

I have different api's writed in nodejs and python. what is a FAST way to call methods/events and transfer files between then?

is **curl** really fast for high volume of requests? or is there another method to better performance?

maybe socket.io for a permanent connection? or websockets?

Comment: More specifics are needed. The question is unclear to me. Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/)  and its [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) features.

Redis does have a client for both Node.js and Python, so it should offer exactly the functionality you require.